# how to get data from database in List<>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

net MVC, i searched on too many sites to fetch data from database into Listbox but i didn't get any proper answer,

I every site there is a hardcoded example for List<> like this,

```
    public SelectList GetAllCountryList()
    {
        List<Country> objcountry = new List<Country>();
        objcountry.Add(new Country { Id = 1, CountryName = "India" });
        objcountry.Add(new Country { Id = 2, CountryName = "USA" });
        objcountry.Add(new Country { Id = 3, CountryName = "Pakistan" });
        objcountry.Add(new Country { Id = 4, CountryName = "Nepal" });
        SelectList objselectlist = new SelectList(objcountry, "Id", "CountryName");
        return objselectlist;
    }
```

this id the hard coded but i want to fetch it from db and i know i have to apply query
like this

```
public List<Country> allname = new List<Country>
{
    //query
};
```

but i dont know how should i use it,or whether this is correct or not

please help to solve this

Comment: How you make a database call. What is the Repository do you use? Are you using Entity Framework/any/your own DAL?

Comment: i m using Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

In repository you can create like this,

```
public IQueryable<Country> GetCountries()
    {
        return from country in _db.Countries
               orderby country.Name ascending
               select country;
    }
```

In Controller:

In controller Get view you create one viewdata and assign the values into that. No need to create in list..

```
ViewData["Countries"] = new SelectList(_repository.GetCountries(), "Id", "Name");
```

You want to show these all into view means,

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("Countries" + i.ToString(), new SelectList(countries, "Id", "Name"))%>
```

Hope atleast you can get idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to know.

1. How to get data out of a database into a List in C#.
2. How to get a List into your model for display on the page.

The **MVC Music Store Tutorial** at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store covers both of these. It takes a few hours to work through but it will save you a lot more time than it costs.

But for data access, many people use https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ instead of EntityFramework

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework

```
public class YouController:Controller
{
  private YourDBContext db = new YourDBContext();

  public SelectList GetAllCountryList()
  {
    var countries= db.Countries.ToList();
    SelectList objselectlist = new SelectList(countries, "Id", "CountryName");
    return objselectlist;
  }

}
```